# getToken() not giving token

Tags: laravel, jwt

I'm trying to get JWT token from headers using `JWTAuth::getToken()` and this is what i get `"authorization": {},` and while `dd(JWTAuth::getToken())`, it gives response as

```
Token {#360
  -value: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjQsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODAwMC9hcGkvdjEvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1MDAzNjMzNzgsImV4cCI6MTUwMDY2MzM3OCwibmJmIjoxNTAwMzYzMzc4LCJqdGkiOiI0bmkyVmg5RWt1TWtWNnhkIn0.OORKHBnIareDr2Z48pkXN-V3ykUEQRfpfNx5RnQkVI4"
}
```

Is there any way to get token value

Comment: im not sure what authentication you are doing befor that but im using this:
$token = JWTAuth::->attempt(['foo' => 'bar']);

Comment: or maybe try JWTAuth::parseToken()->getToken()

Comment: I did try that. It worked when I parsed it to string `(string)JWTAuth::getToken()`. This gives me the token that I need

Comment: Please post an answer and mark that as accepted. That will tell others that the question is solved. Thank you.

Comment: How do I mark comment as accepted

Comment: You can't "accept" a comment as an answer. In this case you can request @mygeea to post an answer, or do it yourself later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what authentication you are doing befor that but im using this:

```
 $token = JWTAuth::->attempt(['foo' => 'bar']);
```

or maybe try

```
 JWTAuth::parseToken()->getToken()
```

or

```
 (string)JWTAuth::getToken()
```